# Julia lang animation from vector of figures

Tags: animation, julia

I am using Julia and all I am trying to do, is to chain 100 figures into an animation. (I do NOT want to change parameters within a plot in my figure) I can't make it work for hours now, although I think it should be very easy.

Why does the following code not produce a proper animation? (I technically get an animation, but the 100 frames all show the same first figure) I guess, it is because I set the figure fig and "record" only iterates things within this figure, but doesn't change the figure itself. But how do I make it change the figure?

figs is the vector, containing 100 figures.

```
using CairoMakie

frames = range(1,100)
fig = figs[frames[1]]

fps = 20

record(fig, "test.mp4", frames;
        framerate = fps) do frame
    fig = figs[frame]
end
```

Comment: Is my question too simple to be answered? I still could not find the solution to this.

Comment: Looking at the code, you are passing the first frame directly as an argument to the `record` function, so that is probably how it ends up in the video. I would assume you have to call some function to add subsequent frames, not just re-assign to the `fig` variable. But I cannot find documentation on the `record` function, and your code is not enough for me to reproduce the issue. It would help to add a line that initializes `figs` to contain 100 random figures.